# How to reset class variables/objects to their initial states?

Tags: python, class

I have the following class:

```
class SummableSequence(object):
    initials=[]


    def __init__(self, *initial):

        for i in initial:
            self.initials.append(i)


    def __call__(self, i):
        l=self.initials
        new_number = sum(l)
        for j in range(i):
            new_number=sum(l)
            l.append(new_number)
            del l[0]
        return l
```

When I instantiate it with:

```
new= SummableSequence(0,1)
```

I am expecting the same output every time I call it as:

```
new(5)
```

the output should be 5. It works fine the first time but on running it again, the output changes. I think it's because the value of the list initials is not reset. How can I reset that value to the original value and not have it changed every time I make a call?

Comment: Why do you use a mutable data structure if you don't want mutation? You have a single list shared across all instances and explicitly modify it in every ``__call__``. Your algorithm can be written perfectly fine without mutation.

Comment: no actually the list changes with every instance, with the list items provided at instantiations. e.g:
new= SummableSequence(0,1)
new_2= SummableSequence(03,5,6)

Comment: ``self.initials`` is the sole ``[]`` that you created in the body of ``SummableSequence``. It is not created anew for each instance. In your example, ``new_1.initials`` will be ``[0, 1, 3, 5, 6]``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `__call__` function, you can create a new copy `self.initials` and store it in `l`, and then operate on it, so that the original is unaffected. This can be done as:

```
l = self.initials.copy()
```

in the first line of `__call__`.